# Is there any automated tool for convert PNG to Sprite image?

Tags: tools, automation, sprite, image-sprite

Hi I have a bundle of PNG images I just want convert that all to one Sprite image, I can understand that each PNG image can arrange one by one for Sprite using Photoshop. But the purpose is I want to reduce the arrangement process time. So if anyone have a idea for that please suggest me.

Answer (score 4):

There are tons of web services, that do that for you.
I have not tested many, but I can recommend:

**[ZeroSprites](http://zerosprites.com/)**

ZeroSprites uses the VLSI floorplanning algorithm to optimize the image arrangement and gives you the sprite as a download. You also get the position for each image for different purposes:

- CSS background with pixel positioning
- CSS background with percentage positioning
- tab separated positons for scripting.